Why does Bluetooth le scan return address XX:XX:XX:XX:55:66 in android 14
I have a Bluetooth LE app that has been working fine since android 4.0.  I have fixed the permissions for 14 to add the following to the Manifest


I fixed a few other problems and everything is working fine except when I scan for Bluetooth devices it returns the addresses with xx in the 4th position.
XX:XX:XX:XX:55:66
Anyone run in to this or have any idea what might be causing this?
I can't find any other obvious problems after looking at the list of Changes in Android 14.

I found the answer to my problem.  The code from day 1 for getting the address on the call back result was:
string address = result.Device.ToString();
This used to work fine until Android 14 (34) when returns XX:XX:XX:XX:55:66
The correct code now is:
string address = result.Device.Address.ToString();
Duh!!!!
